# Django+Wordpress+Nginx reverse proxy apache

Tags: django, wordpress, apache, nginx

I have 2 machines one is django (https://orgofoods.com) and another one is wordpress (https://blog.orgofoods.com). Django is running with nginx, gunicorn and the configuration goes like this

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name orgofoods.com;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static;
    }

    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
        alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }
    location /blog {
        proxy_pass  https://blog.orgofoods.com;
    }

    location /blog/wp-content {
        proxy_pass  https://blog.orgofoods.com/wp-content;
    } 
    location /blog/wp-includes {
        proxy_pass https://blog.orgofoods.com/wp-includes;
    }
    location /blog/wp-login.php {
        proxy_pass https://blog.orgofoods.com/wp-login.php; 
    }
    location /blog/wp-admin {
        proxy_pass https://blog.orgofoods.com/wp-admin;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;

            proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/orgofoods.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/orgofoods.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = orgofoods.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name orgofoods.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

but when i try to access orgofoods.com/blog it is returning 404 error, and the request is handled by nginx where as it needs to be handled by apache, please any one can shed some light on it.

[dev tools network screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqYta.png)
Thanks in advance

p.s.: i followed this tutorial  (https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2016/12/11/wordpress-nginx-proxy-server-subdomain-subdirectory)

Comment: you might need the resolver statement. for example: `resolver 8.8.8.8;`

Comment: i followed this tutorial [link](https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2016/12/11/wordpress-nginx-proxy-server-subdomain-subdirectory/), its a static ip so do we still need resolvers in the case of static ips.

Comment: I get what you are trying to achieve and makes sense, but something that makes even more sense is that you point your blog subdomain via DNS to the apache server and then your Nginx has only to make a permanent redirect, this approach is more SEO friendly.